# Java bug/inconsistency adding float and int values

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, precision

Check this code:

```
    public static void checkBug() {
        int a = 16763383;
        int b = 16763383;

        float myFloat = 222778.0f;
        int myInt = 222778;

        a += myInt;
        b += myFloat;
        System.out.println("A is : " + a + " and B is: " + b);
    }
```

The result is `A is : 16986161 and B is: 16986160`

Why this discrepancy? I have been testing with many values of `a`, `b`, `myFloat` and `myInt` but I could no find any proper explanation why it happens with these particular values.
Also, I can execute/compile `b += myFloat;` but I cannot do it with `b = b + myFloat;`.

Comment: Printing `b+myFloat` (*before* you change `b`) might give you a clue.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119225/why-is-there-a-precision-loss-for-floating-point-numbers

Comment: This doesn't necessarily seem surprising, given the imprecision of `float`.